# print number having digit 3 or 6 from 1 to 1000.like 3 ,6,13,16.....996,

Tags: java

Here is my code. When the value of the number is less than 100, output is correct but when the value of number is 1000.output is wrong

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i,x,y,z,num;
        int number=1;

        for(;number<1000;number++) {
            i=number;
               while (i > 0) {
                z=i%10; //System.out.println( "digit="+z);
                if(((z%3==0)&&(z%9!=0)&&(z!=0))||(z%6==0)&&(z!=0)) //condition for divisiblity by 3 or 6 and not by 9
                {
                    System.out.println( "number="+number);  
                    break;
                }
                i = i / 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because your loop is till 999 only

Comment: I guess your `if` condition can be simplified to `z==3 || z==6`

Comment: No, 9 is divisible by 3

Comment: @sachinsarwesh In case you want number to __have__ 3 or 6 , you can use first statement in my answer or if you want all numbers to __start__ with 3 or 6 , you can use second statement in my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51503684/1262248

Answer (score 3):

This is much shorter and makes a whole lot more sense.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
   String str = Integer.toString(i);

      for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
          if(str.charAt(j) == '3' || str.charAt(j) == '6')
              System.out.println("nuber =  "+ i);
      }
   }
```

Comment: `String.contains` will do the task :)

Comment: @sachinsarwesh I think that is what you want 513, 516 and 996 seems all to be valid case as all contains either 3 or 6

Comment: @sachinsarwesh, it prints from 3, 6 ... 996, check your output again

Comment: it should start from 3,not from 513

Comment: @sachinsarwesh now thats bad... as your question says print-number-having-digit-3-or-6 ... Please update your question...513 also __have__ 3

Comment: The question seems to ask for all numbers that have a 3 or a 6 in them.. up to 1000. This outputs from 3 - 996.

Comment: @CU_dev even I thought so, but it seems the requirement have changed :D

Comment: @CU_dev +1 for your start at SO and your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine, the only thing missing is your loop is till 999.

Also, In Java 8, you can simply do :

```
IntStream.range(1,1001).mapToObj(p->Integer.toString(p)).filter(p->p.contains("3")||p.contains("6")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
3
6
13
16
.
.
993
996
```

-- EDIT --

In case you want all numbers starting from 3 or 6, you can use below one:

```
IntStream.range(1,1001).mapToObj(p->Integer.toString(p)).filter(p->p.charAt(0)=='3'||p.charAt(0)=='6').forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
3
6
30
31
32
.
.
.
.
698
699
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be complicating things here. Instead I’d go with:

```
IntStream.range(1,1000)
         .filter(n -> String.valueOf(n).matches(“3|6”))
         .forEach(n-> System.out.println(“number “ + n));
```

Or the imperative approach:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
     if(String.valueOf(i).matches(“3|6”))
         System.out.println(“number “+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick,

```
for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i++) 
    if (String.valueOf(i).contains("3") || String.valueOf(i).contains("6"))
        System.out.println(i);
```